# import Pubnub into Angular2 webpack app

Tags: angular, webpack, pubnub

I am trying to import PubNub into my Angular 2 webpack project. I successfully installed the pubnub npm package and included the import of PubNub into my vendor folder which webpack imports on building the vendor file and inserts into my index.html file. For some reason I can not import it into my angular 2 service

vendor.ts

```
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';
// RxJS
import 'rxjs';
import 'bootstrap-loader';
import 'PubNub';
```

pubnub.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import PubNub from 'PubNub';
@Injectable()
export class PubNubService {
constructor (
    private pubNub: PubNub
) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include it in your module.
The service needs to be provided by some module.
Also Pubnub has different module for angular2
[read here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angular2-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { PubNubAngular } from 'pubnub-angular2';
import { AppComponent } from './appComponent';
@NgModule({
    imports:[ BrowserModule ],
    declarations:[ AppComponent ],
    providers:[ PubNubAngular ],
    bootstrap:[ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor() {}
}
```